# In which scenarios should I use std::endl instead of '\n'?

Tags: c++11

I came to know that std::endl is actually a performance barrier in programs with lots of stream outputs are there. If that is the case, can anyone share the actual necessity of using std::endl while coding in C++?

Comment: Portability....

Comment: It's when you need to flush the stream. That's it.

Comment: @iBug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n#comment2241883_213977